# What purpose did the kanji read "たいと" (雲雲雲龍龍龍) serve?

Tags: kanji

Back in the day, my friends and I derived much amusement from the kanji that is read 「たいと」, which consists of three 雲 and three 龍:

[image: たいと]

What actual purpose did this kanji serve? The [Japanese Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8) for it says:

> 日本で苗字として用いられたとされる国字。

But the fact that this says 用いられた**とされる** suggests to me that this is somehow vague, unclear, or disputed.

(Personally, it strikes me as an almost comical kanji, and I can't imagine anybody using it seriously.)

Comment: 84 strokes?!?!?!

Comment: I haven't been around many people studying languages, so I derived much amusement from imagining a group of people deriving much amusement from looking at (and maybe writing) a single 漢字.

Comment: "Sensei, we found this interesting kanji. Do you think you could show us how to write it?" / "Sure, which kanji is it?" / "雲雲雲龍龍龍 _chortle chortle chortle_". My friends and I were not exactly master comedians back in high school.

Comment: Almost feels like something for an academic olympic event.  Hold a contest to see who can write it the fastest without resorting to 草書

Comment: Hey, if my name was spelled with that 漢字, you'd better be damn sure I'd hold on to it. Maybe a little gaudy, but definitely unique.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](http://nihonshock.com/2009/10/crazy-kanji-highest-stroke-count/) (skim to the bottom), apparently someone actually used it to write their name as recently as the 1960s (which means he probably was given the name prior to the postwar reforms limited what names could be given to an assigned set).